# How to get time conversion using FFmpeg

Tags: batch-file, ffmpeg

I have tried extracting  `video.mpg` to images using `FFmpeg` command line and it works fine, but I want get time of the conversion process that will be taken till `video.mpg` is extracted, and save to `Time.txt`.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mpg image%d.jpg>>time.txt
```

Where I have been wrong?

Comment: Do you get any information in `time.txt` ?

Comment: Yes I gotta many description ,but not time

Answer (score 0):

ffmpeg outputs the progress messages to `stderr`, so to redirect it to a file use `2>>time.txt`:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mpg image%d.jpg 2>>time.txt
```

More info: http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html

P.S. in batch-files `%` should be doubled: `ffmpeg -i video.mpg image%%d.jpg 2>>time.txt`

Comment: Thanks,its work fine.But another problem I have ,when I put this code in cmd works fine ,but when I create a text file and putting this code in then save it as start.bat not works ,How I will.